# How to print from db to image file in php

Tags: php, pdf

I have an invoice  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxFs0.png which is only available in image format and all of my data is in a MySQL database.
How would I print 'name' to the appropriate field on an image file?
i.e.

```
fprint (x region, y region) etc...  ?
```

Everything I find is for text files.

Comment: Since the invoice is an image, you'll want to bring in the [GD](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library. The image is low in quality, if you really want to draw text on top of it, also attempt to get a clear and straighter image.

Comment: better solution design html as per invoice looks ... or use pre-printed stationery

Comment: @user1844933 The data is from the database, and the invoice probably needs to be emailed/printed to the client. So how does HTML (client side), generate an invoice? This question deals entirely on the server-end.

Comment: GD might be the thing. I am trying to do this the easiest/fastest. Though I have never worked with GD before. Can I burn the image in the background and then set print regions?  Is there a cheesy solution like that?

Comment: @Dave Chen only admin will be printing. I don't have to worry about what customer thinks about the software, only the finished printed product.

Comment: possibly put it in a 8.5 x 11 table? with a bunch of em and margin settings for the text? That would get the text to the correct place, but printing correctly is another issue.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/Cqjc3rgQ) is a quick example of placing `Hello world` on the image. [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UADOB.png) is the resulting image from the code in the link. I'd recommend a higher quality image as stated from my previous comment, or a table as suggested.

Comment: @Dave Chen that looks so cheezy and like a total hack. It's perfect!!! Thank you!  Exactly what I was looking for.   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A candidate for [GD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php):

```
<?php
 
$image = imagecreatefrompng('http://i.imgur.com/h1dnVN8.png');
 
$colorBlack = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($image, 2, 30, 20, 'Hello world!', $colorBlack);
 
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Output:

> [image]